# Leaving postdoc for another one

Tags: postdocs, quitting

I have started my first postdoc for a little less than a year now. It is a two-yrs position. However, my relationship with these new supervisors have been at least questionable. Additionally, my research institute cannot back up the research topic that I have been working with since my PhD, So I had to change my research to accomodate the views of the lab. Because of those reasons my productivity has significantly slowed down since I started the postdoc here.

A few days ago, another professor that I have been sucessfully working with for the last 3 years told me she would open a postdoc position and she would like me to apply for it. I have an incredible relationship with that professor, and I know I can do the type or research i want to do with her and grow a lot academically in her lab.

However I'm worried about leaving my current position midway through the 2 years. Do yall think there is a way for me to leave without bruning some bridges or having a bad impact in my CV? Have anyone had a similar experience? And if so, what did you do?

Comment: Part of the point of doing a post doc is to show you can do something different from your PhD topic. But, if it isn't working out go do something else. Life is short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for it to be interpreted as burning bridges if you present it to your current PI as an unlooked for opportunity and not as dissatisfaction. Don't leave work unfinished, though, if you can possibly avoid it, or at least find a way to pass it on effectively.

There is no reason for it to impact your CV provided that you leave without issues. It is probably easiest to leave at the end of a year and seems like a natural place to leave it.

Talk it over with the other professor, also. You may need to try to match up end and start dates for funding purposes.